# Simple Kivy App that is deployed and has no errors, but when opened has a black screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I created a simple app in Kivy. When I debug and deploy the app everything is fine no errors, but when I download the file on my phone and open it. Nothing happens. https://github.com/r0me777/AnimalNoisesApp.git Github Please help.

Python File:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class AppLayout(GridLayout):
    def play_music(self, MusicName):
        music = SoundLoader.load(MusicName)

        if music:
            music.play()


class ButtonApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonApp().run()
```

Kv File:

```
AppLayout:

<AppLayout>:
    cols:2
    rows:2
    Label:

        text: "Press the Animals!!"
        size: self.texture_size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: Bee
            background_normal: "bee.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
        Button:
            id: Bird
            background_normal: "bird.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("BirdNoise.mp3")
    #    Button:
    #        background_normal: "cow.png"
    #        on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
    #    Button:
    #        background_normal: "dog.png"
    #        on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: Elephant
            background_normal: "elephant.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("ElephantNoise.mp3")
        Button:
            id: Frog
            background_normal: "frog.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("FrogNoise.mp3")
      #  Button:
      #      background_normal: "horse.png"
      #      on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
      #  Button:
      #      background_normal: "koala.png"
      #      on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: Lion
            background_normal: "lion.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("LionNoise.mp3")
        Button:
            id: Seal
            background_normal: "walrus.png"
            on_release: root.play_music("SealNoise.mp3")
    #    Button:
    #        background_normal: "bird.png"
    #        on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
    #    Button:
    #        background_normal: "bird.png"
    #        on_release: root.play_music("BeeNoise.mp3")
```

Both Pretty Simple, and when I bulldozer it no errors. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `def build(self): return AppLayout()` in the `ButtonApp class` ?

Comment: The `Button.kv` should be named `button.kv` (lower case).

Comment: strange I upper cased it when I ran it on my computer with no problems, I will change it. I appreciate the suggestion. @JohnAnderson

Comment: Maybe but I haven't used that build(self) and it still works fine on my computer I will try it though. Thanks to the suggestion @PaulLam

Comment: I think changing the Button.kv from button.kv worked it now shows up on my screen. Something things aren't working like audio but one step closer thank you John! @JohnAnderson

Answer (score 0):

I changed the .kv file from Button.kv to button.kv. Although audio issues have come around, as I cannot hear anything from the app but it got the display working so my question was basically solved.